# How to make unattended-upgrades on Debian to not download via certain wifi SSID

Tags: debian

I have configured my Debian system to run unattended upgrades as per the [relevant Debian Wiki topic](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades).

This works fine, except I would like to not download updates when connected through my mobile Internet connection. I can identify this connection by its WiFi network SSID.

Is there a config option that would let me do this, or would I have to write some shell script and run it as part of the upgrade process to implement such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option for apt-conf for checking for a particular gateway or connection. Therefore, you 'll need to write a bash script which checks the gateway or the interface status, and if matches the right one, the run the upgrade process.